# Underfull vboxes troubleshooting with here figures

Tags: spacing, floats, positioning, boxes

How can I avoid vertical underfull boxes in a document which contains a lot of **Here** figures? My document is pretty big and I ask about general guidelines, so I did not provide a MWE.

I thought setting the spacings after and before the figures/captions etc. to be a multiple of `\baselineskip` should work.

By the same token setting figure height to be a multiple of `\baselineskip` should also help with this case. Do you agree with this?

I cannot change the float placement specifier `[H]` since the figures/tables must be before the text which refers to them.

Comment: I cannot see how you could solve the problem in general simply by making the adjustments you describe.  Let’s say that a page contains 50 lines; suppose you have (1) one line of text, (2) a “here” figure taking up exactly 30 lines, including the vertical space above and below, (3) another line of text, and (4) another 30-lines worth “here” figure: what would you expect LaTeX to do in such a situation?

Comment: by design `H` produces ugly spaces as the reason LaTex floats figures is to avoid those spaces. The fact that you want the figures before they are referenced does not imply that you have to use `H`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Okay I understood the inconsistency.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So the best option is to use `h` I presume.